# Name of transitive group of polynomial with cubic degrees

Tags: symmetric-groups

What is the transitive group details of a polynomial where only the third power terms occur?  That is $x^{3n} + a_{n-1} x^{3(n-1)} + ... + a_1 x^3 + a_0$.  I need the basic theorems that state or prove this group structure.  I think that the answer is $C_{3} \wr {S}_{n}$ from other examples however I do not understand this answer well.  Likewise I need the theorem for the quadratic case of just even powers occurring.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean the Galois group of such polynomials?

Comment: Yes the Galois groups are my focus.

Comment: I encountered an example that simply stated that even power equations of the form ${x}^{2n}+{a}_{n-1}{x}^{2(n-1)}+\cdots+{a}_{1}{x}^{2}+{a}_{0}$ are generic to the hyperoctahedral group ${C}_{2} \wr {S}_{n} = {S}_{2,n} = {B}_{n}$.  OK, this is good, however I need some theorems that make this statement firm and there may be additional restraints and conditions that I am unaware of.